# C# Trigonometry (HELP!)

Tags: c#, trigonometry, xunit, xunit.net

Ok so here's the situation...

I'm currently working on a project for my Math and Physics for Games class.

I finished coding my solution, and ran the xUnit tests that my teacher made for us.

90% of them fail.

I have a **Calculator.cs** file that contains all of the methods that I have coded. Each trigonometric method is made to return a **Tuple**, and that Tuple's items are then used in an **xUnit.Assert.Equal(expectedResult, Math.Round(calculatorTuple.Item1, 4))**...

For example... I have a method named Trig_Calculate_Adjacent_Hypotenuse that accepts two doubles as it's parameters (Angle in degrees and Opposite)

The calculator finds that Adjacent is equal to **15.4235**... 
but my real-life calculations show me that it's **56.7128**.
Therefore when the test runs, it does Assert.Equal(56.7128, 15.4235) and finds that these two answers are not equal. (obviously)

I looked over the code in my Calculator.cs file multiple times... and **cannot for the life of me** find the problem.

Here's my method so you can take a look at it:

```
public static Tuple<double,double> Trig_Calculate_Adjacent_Hypotenuse(double Angle, double Opposite)
    {
        double Hypotenuse;
        double Adjacent;
        // SOH CAH TOA

        // Using TOA to find Adjacent
        // so Adjacent = Opposite / Tan(Angle)
        // so Adjacent = 10 / Tan(10)
        // which means Adjacent = 56.7128
        // However my calculator finds 15.4235 instead...
        Adjacent = Opposite / Math.Tan(Calculator.DegreesToRadians(Angle));

        // Using SOH to find Hypotenuse
        // so Hypotenuse = Opposite / Sin(Angle)
        // so Hypotenuse = 10 / Sin(10)
        // which means Hypotenuse = 57.5877
        // However my calculator finds something different... (unknown due to Adjacent's failure)
        Hypotenuse = Opposite / Math.Sin(Calculator.DegreesToRadians(Angle));

        return new Tuple<double, double>(Adjacent, Hypotenuse);
    }
```

And here's the test method:

```
        [Theory]
    // Student Data
    [InlineData(10, 10, 56.7128, 57.5877)]
    public void TestCalculateAdjacentHypotenuse(double Angle, double Opposite, double Adjacent, double Hypotenuse)
    {
        // Act - performing the action
        Tuple<double, double> results = Calculator.Trig_Calculate_Adjacent_Hypotenuse(Angle, Opposite);

        // Assert - did we get back the correct answer
        Assert.Equal(Adjacent, Math.Round(results.Item1, 4));
        Assert.Equal(Hypotenuse, Math.Round(results.Item2, 4));
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me find out what the problem is! :)

**Thank you!**

Comment: Don't link images, paste the relevant code directly into the question.

Comment: Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: `Math.Tan(Angle)` works with radians,  not with degrees. Did you consider it? Try `Math.Tan((Angle * 3.14)/180);`

Comment: @Roma You found the answer. `10/(tan(10))=15.42` (wrong), `10/(tan(10*3.1415/180))=56.714` (correct).

Comment: Wow I fail, thank you so much guys!

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thank you for informing me of that, I will do my best to include code directly from this point on. I edited the question to include my code. However, my problem is now solved thanks to all these amazing people. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.Tan(Angle)` works with radians, not with degrees (Also `Sin()`, `Cos()` work with radians).

Try `Math.Tan(Angle * Math.PI / 180);`

Comment: Why not use `Math.PI` instead of `3.14`?

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that... I feel stupid now haha. But at least now I know! :)